# How to create an ensemble that gives precedence to a specific classifier

Tags: classification, prediction, ensemble-modeling, binary, ensemble

Suppose that in a binary classification task, I have separate classifiers `A`, `B`, and `C`. If I use `A` alone, I will get a high precision, but low recall. In other words, the number of true positives are very high, but it also incorrectly tags the rest of the labels as `False`. `B`, and `C` have much lower precision, but when used separately, they may (or may not) result in better recall. How can I define an ensemble classifier that gives precedence to classifier `A` only in cases where it labels the data as `True` and give more weight to the predictions of other classifiers when `A` predicts the label as `False`.

The idea is, `A` is already outperforming others in catching true positives and I only want to improve the recall without hurting precision.

Comment: Ensemble models learn the correct weights for you. Read about _boosting_ and _stacking_. You can tune the ensemble classifier to yield the recall/precision trade-off you desire. Welcome to the site!

Comment: can you describe the data? what kind of classifiers you are using?

Answer (score 1):

[Feature-Weighted Linear Stacking](https://arxiv.org/abs/0911.0460) might be what you are looking for.

> FWLS combines model predictions linearly using coefficients that are
>   themselves linear functions of meta-features.

In your example you can use the meta-feature "Does `A` label the example as `True`?"

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description, it looks like different models have different biases. Two important questions: do you have any data imbalance problem? What kind of models you are using? Using stacking based classifier is beneficial if you have different biases. Try to use a simple stack based classifier.
For your level-1 classifier, use different models (e.g. SVM-L, SVM-NL, DT, RF, ... etc). For your meta-data, use probabilities and for the meta-classifier use Random Forest.

If you have a data imbalance problem using stack based classifier is a little bit more challenging.

Answer (score 0):

> *How can I define an ensemble classifier that gives precedence to classifier A only in cases where it labels the data as True and give more weight to the predictions of other classifiers when A predicts the label as False*.

Since, your dependency is on your prediction not on the label.

The best and simple approach would be to do it manually - 

1. Create 3 Models

2. Predict using all 3

3. Call a function to adjust Classifier weights

4. Call weighted Predict

```
###Pseudo-code

def cust_wt(p_a, p_b, p_c):
    if (p_a > THRESHOLD):
        weights = 60:20:20
    else:
        weights = 20:40:40

    my_actual_predict(weights) ##Call the voting Classifier
```

You can use Sklearn's voting classified with different weights.

[VotingClassifier](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.VotingClassifier.html)